# How to Create Custom Permission and Group model in django?

Tags: python, django

i am trying to create my Custom Permission and Group model with following code but when i try to migrate i got error "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_permission" already exists"

```
class Role(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    # slug          = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_group'


# ROLE_CHOICES = (('superuser', 'Super User'),('user', 'User'))

class Permission(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    codename = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
```

---------------------------Settings.py----------------------------

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_filters',
    'sparkAuth',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    codename = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
```

You expect your table to be named `auth_permission` which is already being used by the `Permission` model in the `django.contrib.auth` app. This is why the error says:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_permission" already exists
```

Solution:

- Choose a different table name
- Do not specify the table name, then it will be in the form of `<app>_<modelclass>`
- Another very bad idea would be to remove the `django.contrib.auth` from `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` but then you risk breaking a lot of stuff and you probably really don't want that.